# Grab specific item from JS object using .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Hello fellow developers,
I am trying to get the variable 'title' from a node.js loop for my ticketing system. My goal is to put this variable as a placeholder so when a user tries to edit a ticket, the item is automatically put in the field. I was able to create an Each loop that gets all the titles from the loop but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to grab the specific one. Any help is appreciated!
Loop at top of page:

```
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td class='thetitle'><%= data[i].title %></td>
<td><%= data[i].unitId %></td>
<td><%= data[i].priority %></td>
<td><%= data[i].assignedTo %></td>
<td><%= data[i].description %></td>
<td><%= data[i].date %></td>
```

Bottom code

```
$('.btn-info').click(function(){
    $( ".thetitle" ).each(function( index ) {
        console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
        });
    });
```

This code works and gives me an output like this:
[image: console output]

So the root of my question is how would I grab 1 of those variables based on the CURRENT item.
I'm trying to carry over the variable but it is nested in a loop..
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h9ON.png)
and when the user presses edit it should carry the variable to auto fill the form
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffd06.png)

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing each item individually already in your each loop. You can simply use an if statement in the same section you're printing to the console like so:

```
$( ".thetitle" ).each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
    if($(this).text() == "example") {
        //this code fires when the title of the CURRENT item is "example"
    };
});
```

Comment: OK but I need to grab the current item. So they click a button inside the loop that passes a variable based on what they clicked so that I can autofill the form 'placeholder' parameter with the specific one they chose.

Comment: Something like this.. document.getElementById("edittitle").placeholder = 'Variable based on the ticket they clicked edit on';

Comment: I think you're approaching this wrong @Dannyboy321, I don't see what the foreach loop is for here. Ultimately what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you might be right. I just updated the question with more screen shots to give a better understanding. thanks @Capn Jack

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you looping through all the td elements with class "theTitle", but need to fire event when the ticket in question is being edited. I.E. the user clicked this ticket, so worry about this one only.

It seems that you want to grab the outputted title and place in some form somewhere.

Instead try something like:

```
$('.theTitle').each(function(){
   var $ele = $(this);
   $ele.click(function(e){
    //grab title variable, do editing, etc.
    console.log($ele.text());
   });
});
```

You may need to update the css for td cells to ensure click event is fired.

```
.theTitle{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```